# Android parse delete in background on object still holds the value of objectId

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, row, delete-row

I am using parse as database and I have a table called Address, a user can have multiple addresses. I have an activity which displays a list of address which are tagged to a user. The user can delete edit or add the addresses. Once a user deletes an address there is an option to undo the deletion. So I am using the same address object which I deleted from parse to save again. But the address class is a subclass of ParseObject and it still holds the value of getObjectId(). So when I try to save that address object in background because of the Object Id value it tries to find that particular row in the address table and update it which actually doesn't exists. The error I get is ParseException object not found for update. The code as follows

// deletion code

```
mAddress = mAddressAdapter.getItem(position);
mAddress.deleteInBackground(delete call back) {
       // even after mAddress is successfully deleted from parse table and the row doesn't exists. mAddress.getObjectId() still has some value which should be null or empty after deletion I believe.
       after deletion success option to undo the delete
       if the user selects yes

}
```

//saving the old mAddress object to save again

```
mAddress.saveInBackground(save call back) {
      // here because the mAddress.getObjectId() still has value the parse tries to update the values against the object ID which in background is deleted.
}
```

any idea on how to tackle this problem is much appreciated. I am not sure if this is the normal behaviour or I am missing something here.

Comment: Just trying to get a sense of what is going on...  If the user chooses to delete the address are you deleting it from your db, or are you still storing it   in your db but not showing it to the user?  Also, I don't know if you meant to do this, my apologies, but i'm you mean "SaveCallback" (nothing to do with the comment, just asking).

Comment: I believe when save is called on a parseObject with an objectId it'll automatically try to update the row, since all objectId's are generated in the database, so it assumes the row exists. Maybe try to do something like mAddress.remove("ObjectId"); followed by the mAddress.saveInBackground(); to remove the ObjectId, so that the save thinks it's a new object, since the objectId is missing? I hope this will help you a little bit in the right direction!

Comment: Hi James, I delete it from my database.

Comment: Hi Bart, I have tried that too, but that doesn't help either

Comment: @PunK_l_RuLz What happened when you tried what Bart suggested?

Comment: @Async it still the same problem

Comment: @PunK_l_RuLz Does the objectId get deleted from the object when you do `remove()` or it still stays there?